# Can I use graphic drivers inside my VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, drivers, graphics-card

I’m currently using CAD programs like [Inventor](http://www.autodesk.com/products/inventor/overview), or AutoCAD and it doesnt certify my generic VirtualBox graphic card. Can I install normal drivers for it in my VirtualBox so my Windows can benefit from it?

The VirtualBox server is running on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

No, the GPU inside the VM is emulated, so you can't install your host GPU driver. If you need such programs, that heavily use the GPU, install them on the host and not inside a VM.